# Wordpress posts page is not showing posts list

Tags: wordpress

Im trying to setup custom posts page. I was trying to use home.php, and custom page template. After that i choose in the setting part "Reading Settings" my blog page. Problem is that when i go on www.domain.tld/blog im getting single blog post page, not a list of blogs. When i switch blog template to some other url, then everything is fine but still is not using custom template. In that case wp are using home.php

home.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * Blog listing
 */
?>
<?php get_header() ?>
<div id="blog" class="page_wrapper">
    <div class="hedaer_mini_part">
        <?php get_template_part('parts/navigation'); ?>
        <div class="container">
            <hr>
            <h1>Blog</h1>
            <div class="search">
                <?php echo get_search_form( ); ?>
                <?php
                    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 0;
                    $query = new WP_Query(array('category_name' => 'blog', 'post_type' => 'post', 'paged' => $paged));
                    if ($query->have_posts() || $paged >= 1 && $paged <= $wp_query->max_num_pages) :
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog_lista">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="news_list_wrapper">
                <?php
                // Start the loop.
                while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                ?>
                <div class="news_list_item ffs-able">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <div class="news_list_image">
                                    <!-- <img src="" /> -->
                                    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                                        <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('list_size'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title() ?>" />
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <div class="news_list_content">
                                    <h3 class="title"><?php the_title() ?></h3>
                                    <div class="body">
                                        <?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 90); ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="date">
                                        <?php the_time('j. F Y.'); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <?php
                // End the loop.
                endwhile;
                ?>
        </div>
        <div class="news_pagination">
            <hr>
            <?php the_posts_pagination(array('mid_size' => 1, 'prev_text' => '&lt;', 'next_text' => '&gt;')); ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        else :
            echo 'There is no blog posts..';
        endif;
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add these codes to index.php and not home.php. That might fix the issue.

Comment: I just dont get t why is that on just this project. I have another site where tamplete for page is working fine. And im watchig WP hierarchy and index.php is the last thing that is wp looking; https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/wp-hierarchy.png